Google OAuth Granular Permissions with Google Identity Service
Google is currently transitioning their OAuth sign-in flow to granular permissions.
In their recommended approach for Android applications they write:

If you use auth.api.signin SDK from Play Services to interact with Google OAuth 2.0, you can use requestPermissions function to request the smallest set of scopes needed, and the hasPermissions function to check which scopes the user granted when requesting granular permissions.

However the mentioned auth.api.signin SDK is deprecated. Replacements are Credential Manager for authentication or Google Identity Services for authorization.
Handling granular permissions with auth.api.signin SDK seemed pretty straightforward, but in auth.api.identity I can't find any replacement for the hasPermissions function.
Is there any other way in auth.api.signin to check which scopes the user granted? Or am I missing something else?

You should be able to check which scopes the user granted from the AuthorizationResult object returned from the public methods of AuthorizationClient. The AuthorizationResult object has a method getGrantedScopes() to see what scopes that user had granted access to.

so does that mean I need to remember which scopes were granted by the user on last authorization request? what if the user switches to another google account? what if scopes are revoked in google account settings outside of the app? this approach doesn't seem to cover all these edge cases
